# How can i specify chrome profile using Selenide only

Tags: java, selenide

I want to use Custom driver provider with my configuration.
But in this case selenium instead selenide is used.
Going such way i need to specify path to chromedriver.exe, but Selenide does not require to download it.

How can i use custom driver provider without setting

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path/chromedriver.exe");
```

Call webdriver:

```
switch (conf_browser) {
        case "chrome":
            Configuration.browser = DriverProviderChrome.class.getName();
            break;
```

WebdriverProvider:

```
public class DriverProviderChrome implements WebDriverProvider {
    @Override
    public ChromeDriver createDriver(DesiredCapabilities capabilities) {
        File adf = new File("drivers");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers/chromedriver/win32/75.0.3770.90/chromedriver.exe");
        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        LoggingPreferences logs = new LoggingPreferences();
        logs.enable(LogType.DRIVER, Level.ALL);
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--incognito");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\AntonK\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1");
        chromeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logs);
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
        TestBase_working.log(capabilities.getVersion());
        chromeOptions.merge(capabilities);
        return new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenide calls `WebDriverFactory` to download chromedriver to the local maven repo and init `webdriver.chrome.driver` System property.

You can set driver path automatically this way:

```
  WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
```

Chromedriver path is stored here, but mind that path is not static, it changes when driver gets updated automatically:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().binaryPath
```